# Underline width

Tags: soul, underline

It seems, by using the command `\setul{}{ pt}` in the `soul` package, we can change the underline width. But I don't want to use this package. Is there any other command for changing the underline width to an arbitrary size, without using any specific package?

Comment: Are you wishing to use the native `\underline` macro, or are you open to other solutions that don't use packages?  Does it need to line break?  If yes, does it need to hyphenate?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: Although I prefer to use '\underline' macro, but other suggestions are welcomed. No it dose not need any line break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**REVISED APPROACH**

Here is `\dunderline[<offset of line top>]{<thickness>}{<content>}`.

EDIT: I took Harald's suggestion to place the macro inside of a group, since `\ooalign` changes `\lineskiplimit`.  Without the extra group, the underline can run into the content below on the next line.  With the extra group, as shown in the MWE, extra vertical space is inserted to prevent overlap.

EDITED to use egreg's suggestion of `\sbox0{}`, rather than `\setbox0=\hbox{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}
\newcommand\dunderline[3][-1pt]{{%
  \sbox0{#3}%
  \ooalign{\copy0\cr\rule[\dimexpr#1-#2\relax]{\wd0}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\dunderline{1pt}{This is a test}

\dunderline{2pt}{This is a test}

\dunderline[-.5pt]{2pt}{This is a test}

\dunderline[-6pt]{2pt}{This is a test} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL OFFERING**

The magnification is arbitrary, but only between 1x and 2x the original thickness.  It performs the result with a double underline.  Since an underline is .4pt thick, the 1st parameter offset can only vary between 0pt (1x mag) to .4pt (2x mag).

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\dunderline[2][.4pt]{%
  \raisebox{-#1}{\underline{\raisebox{#1}{\smash{\underline{#2}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\underline{This is a normal thickness}

\dunderline[.2pt]{This is 1.5x thickness}

\dunderline{This is 2x thickness}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should you wrap the `\ooalign` in a group, perhaps? It sets `\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen`, after all.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I didn't know that, so thank you, I will edit.  Without it, the dunderline can interfere with what is below.

Comment: I'd recommend `\sbox0{...}` rather than `\setbox0=\hbox{...}`; the former is color safe, the latter isn't.

Comment: This is a nice command! I'm looking to use it in section titles. Is there any way of making a switch? Compare `\textbf{...}` with `\bfseries`. I'd be looking for something like `\dulseries{2pt}` to switch to using `\dunderline{2pt}{...}`. I don't know how this would work with stuff like linebreaks, though...

Comment: @SamOT If you can define `\dunderline` to take only a single argument, such as `\newcommand\dunderline[1]{{\sbox0{#1}\ooalign{\copy0\cr\rule[\dimexpr-2pt\relax]{\wd0}{1pt}}}}`, then you might get away with using the `sectsty` package and declaring `\sectionfont{\dunderline}`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick response on an old question `:-)` I've been trying to use `titlesec` (for separate reasons) and I have something working with `soul`+`\setul{}{2pt}`, but it's not perfect. If I need to improve I'll bear your suggestion in mind!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `soul` allows line breaks in underlined material. If you want it, then use `soul`. But you should avoid underlining altogether.

Otherwise, here's a version that is customizable like for `\setul`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\myuldp}
\newlength{\myulthickness}
\newcommand{\setmyul}[2]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else
    \setlength{\myuldp}{#1}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\myulthickness}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\setmyuldepth}[1]{%
  \settodepth{\myuldp}{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\myulalphabet\else#1\fi
  }%
  \addtolength{\myuldp}{0.9pt}% clearance
}
\newcommand{\myulalphabet}{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}
\newcommand{\myulline}{%
  \leaders\hrule
    height -\myuldp
    depth \dimexpr\myuldp+\myulthickness
  \hfil
}
% initialize
\setmyul{0pt}{0.4pt}
\setmyuldepth{}
%%%

\newcommand{\myul}[1]{{\ooalign{#1\cr\myulline\cr}}}


\begin{document}

\myul{Abcdefghi} \myul{abcyj}

\setmyul{}{2pt}

\myul{Abcdefghi} \myul{abcyj}

\setmyul{1pt}{0.4pt}

\myul{Abcdefghi} \myul{abcyj}

\end{document}
```

An empty argument in `\setmyuldepth` uses the whole lowercase alphabet to decide the depth; an empty first argument to `\setmyul` means “don't change the current value”.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the _breadth_ of the underline? Suppose I wanted to underline only 90% of the text starting from middle of A to the middle of j? (Weird question, but I have a use for it in another script :) )

Comment: @KarthikRaman I don't think so (at least with `soul`). Please, add a question with the needed details.

Comment: This worked great for me: ```\newcommand\ul[1]{%
\raisebox{-3pt}{\hspace{0.25ex}\underline{\hspace{-0.25ex}\raisebox{3pt}{\smash{{#1}}}\hspace{-0.25ex}}}\hspace{0.25ex}}```!