# "Monowidth" underline

Tags: width, underline, textwidth

I was trying to find an answer here, but to no avail (sorry if duplicate). [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443439/underline-width) refers rather to thickness than width.

Is there some way how to underline things of the same type (in math mode) with the same underline length (and ideally at the same vertical level)?

That means, for example, if I define a list

```
\underline{\smash{1}}, \underline{\smash{-1}}
```

this looks from bad to very bad (depending on the font, of course), as the - does great harm here (even when not considering the collision with ,):

[image: problem]

What I mean is to make it look something like

[image: solution]

Of course there are hacks to go around this, the natural idea being using `+1` instead, but this should not be preferred.

`\smash`-ing fixes only the "vertical" side of the problem. By the way, an ideal solution would fix the underline lengths for greek letters etc., math style fonts etc., too. `ulem` doesn't help, neither does `soul` (which just seems to `\smash` automagically).

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Added a picture and changed the example a bit.

Comment: Especially for the length "issue", I don't really understand what you are looking for. Maybe you could add a picture of the expected behavior?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks, I've added a picture of the expected behavior. Although now I'm having second thoughts whether the solution looks better at all (especially when used inside brackets, for example).

Comment: I don't think the requested solution looks better, but if you wanted to do it, you could place the content in a fixed-width `\makebox` (making it large enough), and underline the box.