Best package to make a tree with 3 possibilites
I would like to be able to make this kind of trees:

I have a hard time finding the right package: many only allow binary while I need to have 3 possibilities at each rank

forest

forest or tikz-qtree or tikz etc. I'm not sure which ones are limited to binary trees. all those which spring to mind are free of any such limitation?

but if this is to illustrate chemical structures, you might prefer to look at specialist packages.

Update 1: Addressing problem 1 of the initial solution
@cfr managed to figure out a very easy solution for getting the effect of a gap between the intersection points of the lines:

Just simply draw the dashed line first, because when the edges of the tree are drawn over it after, you could just add draw = white and double = black to the edges to create the visual effect of a gap. Here's the adjusted code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing tree

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % For writing with chemical notation
\usepackage{circledsteps} % For putting a circle around d

% I found a custom defined underline to adjust thickness from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443445/318574
\newcommand\dunderline[3][-1pt]{{%
  \sbox0{#3}%
  \ooalign{\copy0\cr\rule[\dimexpr#1-#2\relax]{\wd0}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow = right,
edge from parent/.style = {draw = white, double = black, line width = 0.4mm, shorten > = -3.5pt, shorten < = -3.5pt}, % Added the commands for drawing the edges with 2 colors (black in the center, white to its left and right)
level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 0.5cm}
]
    \draw[dashed, thick] (2,3.5) -- (2, -2.75); % Moved dashed line up so it's drawn first
    \node (a) {\ce{^{2}C} } % Root of tree
        % 1st branch
        child[child anchor = north west] { node {H\Circled{d} } }
        % 2nd branch
        child[child anchor = 165] { node {\ce{C^4} } 
            child[child anchor = 170] { node{H} }
            child[child anchor = west] { node{H} }
            child[child anchor = 190] { node{H} }
        }
        % 3rd branch
        child[child anchor = 195] { node {\ce{C_3} } 
            % Sub-branches of branch 3
            child[child anchor = 170]{ node {H} }
            child[child anchor = west]{ node {\dunderline{1pt}{H} } }
            child{ node {\textbf{O}} }
        }
        % 4th branch
        child[child anchor = 220] { node {\ce{C_1} } 
            % Sub-branches of branch 4
            child[child anchor = 165] { node {H} }
            child[child anchor = west] { node {\dunderline[-1.5pt]{1pt}{(O)} } }
            child[child anchor = 190] { node {\textbf{o} } }
        }
    ;
    \node at (1.3, 3.35) {Rang 1};
    \node at (2.7, 3.35) {Rang 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Original answer
I know you were only looking for packages to draw trees, but I thought I'd give it a try and draw the example tree you provided with tikz:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing tree
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} % For writing with chemical notation
\usepackage{circledsteps} % For putting a circle around d

% I found a custom defined underline to adjust thickness from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443445/318574
\newcommand\dunderline[3][-1pt]{{%
  \sbox0{#3}%
  \ooalign{\copy0\cr\rule[\dimexpr#1-#2\relax]{\wd0}{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
grow = right,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, line width = 0.4mm, shorten > = -3.5pt, shorten < = -3.5pt},
level 2/.style = {sibling distance = 0.5cm}
]
    \node (a) {\ce{^{2}C} } % Root of tree
        % 1st branch
        child[child anchor = north west] { node {H\Circled{d} } }
        % 2nd branch
        child[child anchor = 165] { node {\ce{C^4} } 
            child[child anchor = 170] { node{H} }
            child[child anchor = west] { node{H} }
            child[child anchor = 190] { node{H} }
        }
        % 3rd branch
        child[child anchor = 195] { node {\ce{C_3} } 
            % Sub-branches of branch 3
            child[child anchor = 170]{ node {H} }
            child[child anchor = west]{ node {\dunderline{1pt}{H} } }
            child{ node {\textbf{O}} }
        }
        % 4th branch
        child[child anchor = 220] { node {\ce{C_1} } 
            % Sub-branches of branch 4
            child[child anchor = 165] { node {H} }
            child[child anchor = west] { node {\dunderline[-1.5pt]{1pt}{(O)} } }
            child[child anchor = 190] { node {\textbf{o} } }
        }
    ;
    \draw[dashed, thick] (2,3.5) -- (2, -2.75);
    \node at (1.3, 3.35) {Rang 1};
    \node at (2.7, 3.35) {Rang 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Some remarks
I encountered 3 smaller problems which I couldn't figure out how to solve:

To make the dashed line get "interrupted" and cut when drawn over by the edges of the tree. I know there's a solution to this problem somewhere on the site as I recall having skimmed a question about it, but I can't seem to find it again.
I can't figure out how to make the superscript and subscript appear as far above and below as your example.
I couldn't figure out how to override the style from edge from parent. There were some instances where the automatic alignment of the edges weren't accurate to your example, and I initially (and still ideally) wanted to use something like edge from parent (\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north west) within the 1st branch, for example. The problem was that it'd draw both edges in that case, however, and including [draw=none] as an option would clear both the edge from the style and the specific one. Thus, I resorted to manually changing the anchor by including [child anchor = <anchor>] as an option to some children. This did create a chain effect, however, because changing it also changed the edge from the branch to its sub-branches, and so I wouldn't recommend this solution - especially for large trees with lots of sub-branches!

Hints to solving the 3rd problem could perhaps be found from here, but I didn't manage to decipher it. Links and references to all the listed problems would be appreciated as I may be able to update and improve my answer then. Alternatively, I won't mind if one takes my code, solves these problems and uploads a new answer, either.
Understanding trees in tikz
It may be hard to understand how trees are drawn with tikz. A good way to get a grasp and "predict" where a specific branch is drawn, however, is to remove grow = right in the options of the tikzpicture. This is the default way trees are drawn (growing downward), and you'll notice that it always starts by drawing the left-most branch, and finishes with the right-most branch for each level. When drawing a tree which grows to the right, you must keep this logic, but remember that it has been rotated 90 degrees to the right. This video may help making it easier to understand the basics of trees. She starts drawing trees around the 7 minute mark.

easier than interrupting the dashed line: (1) draw the dashed line either first or on a background layer; (2) use draw=white, double=black for the edges.

Oh wow, nice catch - Thanks! It's a very easy addition and effectively adds the desired effect. I assume this is because the command essentially does so that you now draw two colors on the edges instead of one, right? Where double makes up the middle color and draw is the second color drawn on either side, hence setting it to white to make it appear as if there's a gap around the dashed line and the edges' intersection points, correct?

Before @cfr's fantastic recommendation, I found the solution that I thought could also be used to solve problem number 1: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/716413/318574
This had lead me on track to try and replicate the example provided on page 22 of the spath3 library's documentation, but it does seem a bit more tricky to implement. For now, I'll use @cfr's solution.

yes, that's exactly what it does. double lines in tikz are essentially 2 lines one on top of the other, with the upper one white. but you can change that colour, as well as the ordinary line colour. :-)

Here is one way to do it with forest, and some plain-Tikz for the dashed line and text.
As you can see, the basic structure to use is like this, using [ .. ] to define branches:
    [\ce{^2C}
        [\ce{C1}  [o][(O)][H]]
        [\ce{C3}  [O][H][H]]
        [\ce{^4C} [H][H][H]]
        [H]
    ]

Later you can add more options to a given branch, like color, separation etc.
If you uncomment %                draw,dotted   % for demonstration only in \forestset you can see the shape of the nodes forest places, e.g. to better understand the apparent variation in line length as a result of nodes adapting to the text they contain.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}
 \forestset{
    default preamble={
        for tree={grow'=east,   % grow right, reverse=true
                  s sep=4mm,    % separation
 %                draw,dotted   % for demonstration only
                  }
    }
 }
 
 \begin{forest}
    [\ce{^2C}, s sep=15mm       % separation here
        [\ce{C1}          [o,red]    [\underline{(O)}][H]]
        [\ce{C3}          [O,magenta][\underline{H}]  [H]]
        [\ce{^4C}         [H]        [H]              [H]]
        [H, name=H]
    ]
    % ~~~ draw the line using relative coordinates, place nodes ~~~
    \draw[dashed] (H)++(.55,-.5) -- 
                     ++(0,12.5) node[anchor=north east]{Rang 1}
                                node[anchor=north west]{Rang 2};
 \end{forest}
\end{document}


s sep'=4mm would be faster.

+1. Amazing solution. Simple and effective. It doesn't seem like you sacrifice that much of tikz level customization, either. The only thing you may want to add is that trees grow in the opposite order of tikz trees. Your tree grows starting from the right-most branch (or, "top and down" if we translate to the right growth direction) while tikz grows from the left-most branch (or, "bottom and up" for right growth direction)

Thank you. BTW, forest is built in Tikz. The pro-users can certainly code it even better
